# How to calculate the difference between the highest value node and the lowest value node with XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

XML example file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<data> 
    <book num="b1"> 
        <title>book1</title> 
        <author>auth1</author>
        <price>5</price> 
    </book> 
    <book num="b2"> 
        <title>book2</title> 
        <author>auth2</author>
        <price>10</price> 
    </book> 
     <book num="b3"> 
        <title>book2</title> 
        <author>auth1</author>
        <price>12</price> 
    </book> 
</data>
```

I need to return a value (maximum price-minimum price).

```
data/book[not(../book/price> price)]/title
```

gave me the title of the book with the highest price

and

```
data/book[not(../book/price<price)]/title
```

gave me the title of the book with the lowest price

but how do I get the value?

*** i also need to return all authors who wrote 2 or more books
I tried :

```
//author[count(parent::book)>=1]/text()
```

but no success :-(

Answer (score 1):

Just subtract the minimum value from the maximum value:

```
data/book[not(../book/price > price)]/price 
- data/book[not(../book/price < price)]/price
```

Applied within an **XSLT 1.0 stylesheet**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="data/book[not(../book/price > price)]/price 
                             - data/book[not(../book/price &lt; price)]/price" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you could use **XPath 2.0**, then you could use the [min()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-min) and [max()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-max) functions. Applied within an **XSLT 2.0 stylesheet**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="max(data/book/price) - min(data/book/price)" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

To find the authors that occur two or more times, you could use the following XPath:

```
(/data/book/author[../following-sibling::book/author = .])[1]
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I am using : http://emdin.info/r/xpath_checker/             I am not sure what should i enter to get the result value...could you help me please?

Comment: That site doesn't appear to work for any/all XPath statements. It may expect the XPath the select and return a `node()`. You might want to try against another site or tool. A quick google search found this tool, which does produce the number 5: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Answer (score 0):

If the previous answer for finding authors does not work, try this:

```
(/inventory/book/author[(../following-sibling::book/author = . )
```

and not

```
(../preceding-sibling::book/author = . )])
```